# clearing a vector or defining a new vector, which one is faster

Tags: c++, vector

Which method is faster and has less overhead?

Method 1:

```
void foo() {
  std::vector< int > aVector;
  for ( int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i ) {
     aVector.clear();
     aVector.push_back( i );
  }
}
```

Method 2:

```
void foo() {
  for ( int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i ) {
     std::vector< int > aVector;
     aVector.push_back( i );
  }
}
```

You may say that the example is meaningless! But this is just a snippet from my big code. In short I want to know is it better to

"create a vector once and clear it for usage"

or

"create a new vector every time"

**UPDATE**

Thanks for the suggestions, I tested both and here are the results

Method 1:

```
 $ time ./test1

 real    0m0.044s
 user    0m0.042s
 sys     0m0.002s
```

Method 2:

```
$ time ./test2

real    0m0.601s
user    0m0.599s
sys     0m0.002s
```

Clearing the vector is better. Maybe this help someone else :)

Comment: "clearing a vector or defining a new vector, which one is faster" - benchmark it an you'll know. There's no general statement that could be made, since this depends on so many platform- and implementation-specific details.

Comment: Agree, but I want to know how g++ generate an optimized code for the methods. Which one is better for compiler?

Comment: I would expect the `clear` method to be faster, if there is any difference.

Comment: @mahmood Then why don't you write a test-case for it, compiled with `g++`? I can't tell the results off the top of my head (nor do I want to do so -- I hate making incorrect assumptions out of air).

Comment: Clear should be faster, because vector frequently doesn't "shrink" when clear() is called.

Comment: I suspect your example was compiled without optimization - I expect BOTH of these examples to be optimized to "Nothing", since the vector is not actually used.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `clear()` is most likely to be faster, as you will retain the memory that has been allocated for previous `push_back()`s into the vector, thus decreasing the need for allocation.

Also you do away with 1 constructor call and 1 destructor call per loop.

This is all ignoring what you're compiler optimizer might do with this code.

Answer (score 0):

To create an empty vector is very little overhead. To GROW a vector to a large size is potentially quite expensive, as it doubles in size each time - so a 1M entry vector would have 15-20 "copies" made of the current content.

For trivial basic types, such as `int`, the overhead of creating an object and destroying the object is "nothing", but for any more complex object, you will have to take into account the construction and destruction of the object, which is often substantially more than the "put the object in the vector" and "remove it from the vector". In other words, the constructor and destructor for each object is what matters.

For EVERY "which is faster of X or Y" you really need to benchmark for the circumstances that you want to understand, unless it's VERY obvious that one is clearly faster than the other (such as "linear search or binary search of X elements", where linear search is proportional to X, and binary search is log2(x)).

Further, I'm slightly confused about your example - storing ONE element in a vector is quite cumbersome, and a fair bit of overhead over `int x = i;` - I presume you don't really mean that as a benchmark. In other words, your particular comparison is not very fair, because clearly constructing 1M vectors is more work than constructing ONE vector and filling it and clearing it 1M times. However, if you made your test something like this:

```
void foo() {
  for ( int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i ) {
     std::vector< int > aVector;
     for(j = 0; j < 1000; j++)
     {
         aVector.push_back( i );
     }
  }
}
```

[and the corresponding change to the other code], I expect the results would be fairly similar.

Comment: std::vector dynamically allocates memory. When dynamic allocation routines are called very frequently (as in this example), they turn into big bottleneck, even if data has no constructors. Because clear() does not normally shrink the internal data, calling clear will be faster.

Comment: @SigTerm: Yes, but you can also use `aVector.resize(1000)` to avoid that allocation. But like I said, it depends on what is stored IN the vector.

Comment: If the goal is to `push_back` elements, then `aVector.reserve(1000)` would be more accurate.