# the values of v2 is not coming out to be correct

Tags: c++, function, vector

I am trying to display the values of v2. If you run the code, you can see that the first value of v2 is correct, but the second value is just a repetition of the first value. I have used vector of vectors for my code. I am dealing with column vectors here. I would appreciate if you could let me know my errors.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<vector<int> > set_val(int M)
{
    vector<vector<int> > v1(M, vector<int> (1));

    for(int i=0;i<M;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<1;j++)
        {
            cin>>v1[i][j];
        }
    }
    return v1;
}

vector<vector<int> > cal_val(int M, vector<vector<int> > &v1)
{
    vector<vector<int> > v2;
    vector<int> temp;

    for(int i=0;i<M;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<1;j++)
        {
            temp.push_back(v1[i][j]-1);

        }
        v2.push_back(temp);
    }
    //display v2
    for(int i=0;i<M;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<1;j++)
        {
            cout<<"v2["<<i<<"]["<<j<<"]:  "<<v2[i][j]<<endl;
        }
    }
    return v2;
}

int main()
{
    int M;
    cout<<"Enter data: ";
    cin>>M;
    vector<vector<int> > v1(M, vector<int> (1));
    vector<vector<int> > v2(M, vector<int> (1));

    v1=set_val(M);
    v2=cal_val(M,v1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please describe what your code should do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the line `for(int j=0;j<1;j++)` in your `cal_val` function, I deduce that you want `v2` to also be a vector of vectors that each have size `1`. So I think that adding `temp.clear();` in this part of the code

```
for(int i=0;i<M;i++)
{
    temp.clear();
    for(int j=0;j<1;j++)
    {
        temp.push_back(v1[i][j]-1);

    }
    v2.push_back(temp);
}
```

should fix the problem. The reason is that otherwise, you will be appending repeatedly to `temp` and therefore it will no longer have size `1` Also, note that you shouldn't usually be passing copies of vectors of vectors, but that you should pass them around as references or use move semantics.

Additionally, I disagree with some of the other answers that advocate creating a new `temp` object in each iteration of the `for` loop. This is because `clear()` will be faster than creating the object (you avoid going through constuctors/destructors in each loop, and also wont allocate as much memory, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189699/clearing-a-vector-or-defining-a-new-vector-which-one-is-faster) for a discussion on that topic).

Comment: it is fixed. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Please don‘t mix up your code and simplify it for readability.

You can create your vectors in the main loop and pass it also as &v1 to set_val
as parameter. Populate it there and return an error code for example.

Don‘t write loops with a size of 1 simple use v1[i][0].

Pass v2 as parameter &v2 to calc_val and calc like v2[i][0] = v1[i][0] - 1.
Remove the temp vector.

for example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int set_val(
   int M,
   vector< vector<int> > &v1
) {
    if(M <= 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
       cout << "Enter value for v1[" << i << "][0] : ";
       cin >> v1[i][0];
    }

    return 0;
}

int calc_val(
    int M, 
    vector< vector<int> > &v1,
    vector< vector<int> > &v2
) {

    if (M <= 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        v2[i][0] = v1[i][0] - 1;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        cout << "v2[" << i << "][0] = " << v2[i][0];
    }

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int M;

    cout << "Enter size of vector  : "; 
    cin >> M;

    vector< vector<int> > v1(M, vector<int> (1));
    vector< vector<int> > v2(M, vector<int> (1));

    int ret = set_val(M, v1);

    if (ret == -1) {
       cout << "Parameter M error.";
    } else {
       ret = calc_val(M, v1, v2);

       if (ret == -1) {
           cout << "Parameter M error.";
       }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If this works you can extend it to support multiple vector dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make new `temp` vector each loop. Change

```
vector<vector<int> > v2;
vector<int> temp;

for(int i=0;i<M;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<1;j++)
    {
        temp.push_back(v1[i][j]-1);

    }
    v2.push_back(temp);
}
```

to

```
vector<vector<int> > v2;

for(int i=0;i<M;i++)
{
    vector<int> temp; //<--- moved here

    for(int j=0;j<1;j++)
    {
        temp.push_back(v1[i][j]-1);

    }
    v2.push_back(temp);
}
```